# почему не работает второй цикл?

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

почему не запускается второй цикл который складывает элементы между нулями

```
public class arrayMin {
    public static void arrNull(){
        int[]ar={0,6,5,8,4,9,0,1,2};

        for (int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
            System.out.println("до "+ar[i]);
         }

        for (int j=1;j<ar[6];j++){
            ar[j]=ar[j]+ 4;
            System.out.println("после "+ar[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: j < 6, наверное, а не j < ar[6]

Comment: я тебя люблю! спасибо